# How to use cattr_accessor in refinement [without rails]

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, activesupport

I want to use `cattr_accessor` from `active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors` in the class `refinement`

```
  require 'active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors'

  module ExtendedString
    refine String do
      cattr_accessor :separator
    end
  end
```

But I got the error:

```
 block in <module:ExtendedString>': undefined method `cattr_accessor' for #<refinement:String@Truncator::ExtendedString> (NoMethodError)
```

How I can use `cattr_accessor` in class rifinement?

Answer (score 0):

I would post it as a comment (cause it doesn't provide a solution), but it needs formatting.

To answer why it fails:

ActiveSupport's `core_ext.rb` that facilitates `cattr_accessor` is monkey patching core object `Class` while the ruby doc says about refinements:

> ... self in the refine block is this anonymous module similar to Module#module_eval.

So, obviously `cattr_accessible` would not be not accessible from within refinements.

And even if it would, `cattr_accessible` (precisely `cattr_writer`, `cattr_reader`) methods are using `class_eval` that affects the global scope anyways which defeats the purpose of refinements.

Comment: So refinements doesn't provide the *full* set of tools for monkey patching? ;)

Comment: @freemanoid Yeah, basically. Refinements have some (well, a lot) limitations which are needed to get a decent performance. However, it’s currently the only option to isolate “monkey-patches” in some scope, that is essential for using “monkey-patches” in gems.